# Serratus anterior

Tags: muscle, bodyweight-exercises, muscle-mass, muscle-gain, growth

Which one of the two exercises can build more the serratus anterior; scapular presses on plank(one arm) or scapular presses on handstand?

first one consits on getting down to an one arm plank and shrugging the shoulder down and up, the later is the same thing but on a handstand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handstand shrug is [scapula elevation](https://exrx.net/Articulations/Scapula#Elevation), in which the trapezius and levator scapulae will do most of the work. The plank may be a better position, but serratus anterior is more active when the arms are elevated higher than 90° from the torso[[1]](https://www.jospt.org/doi/pdf/10.2519/jospt.2006.2306?code=jospt-site), with somewhere mid-way between plank and handstand probably being optimal.

So your likely best bet is to do the plank with feet elevated, such that your hips are higher than your shoulders, but your arm is still vertical.